# How can I resolve the ambiguity in this Microsoft.Office.Excel method call?

Tags: c#, excel

I am using office 2007 excel work sheet function in c# code.
VS2010 issues this warning

> Warning   3   Ambiguity between method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Activate()'
>   and non-method
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.DocEvents_Event.Activate'.
>   Using method
>   group.    D:\EXLANEDB01p\dev\libraries\EXCEL\Excel.cs 531 95  EXCEL

How do I resolve this ?
the call is

```
xSheet.Activate();
```

where `xSheet` passed as ref in the call as

```
ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xSheet
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to disambiguate the `Activate` name. Within the Worksheet interface, `Activate` is either a method (if looked at as a `_Worksheet` object) or an event (if looked at as a `DocEvents_Event` object).

Cast your object to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet` first then call `Activate()`.

```
((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)xSheet).Activate();
```

Or declare a new `_Worksheet` variable and use that within your method.

```
_Worksheet sheet = xSheet;
sheet.Activate();
```

Otherwise you could change your method declaration to take a reference to a `_Worksheet` instead of a `Worksheet` as well as all associated declarations.

```
void MyMethod(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet xSheet)
{
    // ...
}

// usage:
_Worksheet sheet = new Worksheet();
MyMethod(ref sheet);
```

Comment: @Protector: We need to disambiguate the `Activate` name.  Within the `Worksheet` interface, `Activate` is either a method (if looked at as a `_Worksheet` object) or an event (if looked at as a `DocEvents_Event` object).  The compiler wasn't sure what to do about it so we (the programmer) needed to tell what to do with it.  In this case, we should look at it as a worksheet where the name `Activate` is a method.

Comment: Additionally, we could have avoided this all together if we declared the variable to be a `_Worksheet` in the beginning instead of the interop type `Worksheet` which implements both `_Worksheet` and `DocEvents_Event` interfaces.  i.e., `_Worksheet xSheet = new Worksheet();`